# How can I write variable definition without declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I can write declaration or declaration with definition. Examples:

```
int x = 1; // declaration and definition
extern int x; // only declaration
bool f(); // only declaration
bool g() {} // declaration and definition
class X; // declaration
class X {}; // declaration and definition
```

So we can see that this is possible to write only declaration and declaration with definition.
But how I can write only definition? I heard that this is possible.

Comment: For class members outside of the class? (Not sure if their definitions count as declarations).

Comment: Why? Out of curiousity or is there a problem you need to solve?

Comment: Have a read of [Definitions and ODR (One Definition Rule)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: `bool g() {};` should be `bool g() {}` Your version is valid C++, but then so is `;;;;;` -- the semicolon is not related to the function definition at all.

Comment: Technically EVERY definition is also a declaration. Informally some people might at times say that "this is a definition, not a declaration", but that just confuses things.

Comment: There are anonymous: enumerations, structs, classes, namespaces and there are lambdas (functions or function objects without name). I not sure if this counts as definition without declaration but there is nothing else what can be closer to this pointless requirement.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Declaration=="There is an X". Definition=="Here is the X". You simply can't say "Here is the X" while denying that an X exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no definition without a declaration, since the meaning of the first term includes the second. Further, I provided some information from the C++ drafts (6.2. Declarations and definitions):

> A declaration is said to be a definition of each entity that it
> defines.

Link: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def

Comment: That particular wording is needed for definitions containing multiple names, such as `struct Foo {  } myFoo, anotherFoo;`. It's usually better to use one definition per name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a definition for something that is undeclared, point blank. But you do have C++ constructs for writing definitions that may not serve as a first declaration. Here they are:

```
struct C {
    static int i;
};

int C::i = 1;

namespace N {
    extern int i;
}

int N::i = 2;
```

Neither `int C::i = 1;` nor `int N::i = 2;` may serve as an initial declaration for `i`. Those definitions are invalid unless a previous declaration of each respective `i` is present. So in a way they are non-declaring definitions.

This answer may be contentious, and possibly not fall under the answers you had in mind, but those would be the examples.

Answer (score 0):

The variable declaration means, specifying the type and name of the variable.
Example: `int A` means the type of variable (memory location in memory) is `int`, and the name is `A`.
But in variable definition, memory is allocated for the variable, and value is assigned.